# Socket com C# e java

Tags: java, c#

Bom dia, estou escrevendo uma aplicação onde o server socket é em C#(devido há alguns drivers tem que ser em c#) e o cliente em Java.
Consigo fazer a comunicação perfeitamente entre eles, porém ao passar dados, tenho o seguinte erro:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argumento especificado estava fora do intervalo de valores válidos.
>   Nome do parâmetro: size
>      em System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>      em testes.handleClinet.doChat() na d:\c#\socket\testes\handleClinet.cs:linha 40

Código Server c#:

```
//Class to handle each client request separatly
public class handleClinet
{
    TcpClient clientSocket;
    string clNo;
    public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket, string clineNo)
    {
        this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;
        this.clNo = clineNo;
        Thread ctThread = new Thread(doChat);
        ctThread.Start();
    }
    private void doChat()
    {
        int requestCount = 0;
        byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10000];
        string dataFromClient = null;
        Byte[] sendBytes = null;
        string serverResponse = null;
        string rCount = null;
        requestCount = 0;
        while ((true))
    {
        try
        {
            requestCount = requestCount + 1;
            NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            Console.WriteLine(" >> " + (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
            networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
            dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
            dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
            Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "From client-" + clNo + dataFromClient);

            rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount);
            serverResponse = "Server to clinet(" + clNo + ") " + rCount;
            sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
            networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
            networkStream.Flush();
            Console.WriteLine(" >> " + serverResponse);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" >> " + ex.ToString());
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Código Client: Java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      String sentence;
      String modifiedSentence;
      BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 9999);
      DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
      sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
      outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
      modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
      System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
      clientSocket.close();
}
```

Novo client em Java:

```
public class Cliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9999);
            InputStream i = s.getInputStream();
            OutputStream o = s.getOutputStream();
            String str;
            while(true){
                byte[] line = new byte[100];
                System.in.read(line);
                o.write(line);
                i.read(line);
                str = new String(line);
                System.out.println(str.trim());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Grato pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitua:

```
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
```

Por:

```
int read = networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, bytesFrom.Length);
```

Substitua:

```
dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
```

Por:

```
dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom, 0 , read);
```

E ainda ponha todo o conteúdo depois de `int read =` num `if`, assim:

```
if ( read > 0 )
{
    ...
}
```

#### A explicação

`.ReceiveBufferSize` diz o tamanho do buffer disponível, não quantos dados tem nele. O método, nesse caso é `.Available`. Aliás, sugiro trocar o primeiro pelo outro.

O problema na primeira linha substituída é que `.ReceiveBufferSize` pode ser muito maior que `bytesFrom.Length`, o que dá esse erro. `.Read` espera que você passe o máximo que pode ler, e o máximo que pode ler é o tamanho de `bytesFrom`, não o tamanho do buffer do socket.

Pois isso é importante ver o *retorno* de .Read, pois você não sabe quantos bytes foram efetivamente lidos. Não dá para confiar em `.Available`, tem de pegar o retorno mesmo. Disso já segue a justificativa da segunda substituição. Do jeito que estava, você estava sempre criando uma string de 10.000 chars, mesmo que tivesse recebido só um byte.

O `if` não é importante desde que se garanta que o socket é bloqueante. Mas se não tiver garantia, então o `if` é necessário por um `.Read` pode retornar depois de ter lido zero bytes, que dá erro em várias das funções chamadas subsequentemente.

Comment: Muito bom, resolveu o problema. Fiz alguns testes simulando o ambiente real, onde vou ter uma requisição do lado cliente de um ID específico, a partir desta requisição, o serverSocket vai monitorar um equipamento e retornar seu valor em tempo real(em torno de 250ms). Coloquei um for para simular como um contador e ele fez toda a operação, porém o client(Java) não reconheceu sendo necessário interagir manualmente. Teria como o client ler a resposta a medida em que ela for gerada do server? Eu fiz uma mudança no client, vou postar o novo código. Grato pela ajuda.

Comment: Essa já é outra questão, mas a resposta é sim, tem como o cliente ler a resposta assim que ela chega. Estude sobre "Blocking vs. non-blocking sockets". Blocking trava o .Read se não tiver nada, non-bloking não trava e retorna zero. Seu novo cliente Java tem os mesmos problemas da versão C#. Você não está guardando ou testando o retorno de .read(), portanto não sabe quantos bytes foram lidos.